# Only view rows in datagrid that meet a certain condition

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datagrid

One of the columns in my datagrid (**dataGridView1**) is called **DatePaid** and on button click i.e:

```
private void viewOverdue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // details here
}
```

I want it to show all rows in the datagrid that are 2 weeks or older in the **DatePaid** column (using the variable **cRentStart** as a starting point - which is a date in itself in the dd/mm/yyy format). All dates have to be in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter your full list of records and then rebind the new filtered list.

```
private void viewOverdue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Records[] filteredRecords = allRecords.Where(x => x.DatePaid <= cRentStart).ToArray();
    dateGridView1.DataSource = filteredRecords;
    dateGridView1.DataBind();
}
```

This should work if both values are actually of a date type, else you must convert your values to a date.

if they are Strings for example, the query should look like this:

```
Records[] filteredRecords = allRecords.Where(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.DatePaid) <=  Convert.ToDateTime(cRentStart)).ToArray();
```

Note that this conversion only works if the culture of the application sees your string as dd/MM/yyyy, if your culture is en-US for example it would see it as MM/dd/yyyy

The records class should be replace by your own class off course